# Dishwasher Unloading: Optimal Algorithm

Tags: probability, algorithms

Suppose you are unloading cutlery from a dishwasher containing $4$ types of cutlery: teaspoons, tablespoons, knives and forks. Each type has 8 pieces. You hang the cutlery on a rack with two sides. There are four slots for each cutlery type on each side. Assume one side is facing you at any given time. Now, assume the following costs exist:

- $h$ is the cost of hanging a piece of cutlery on the side facing you
- $r$ is the cost of reaching around and hanging on the other side
- $t$ is the cost of turning the rack around so that it faces you

Now, assuming that the next piece of cutlery is chosen randomly from the dishwasher. That is, with probability $1/m$ where $m$ is the number of pieces remaining in the dishwasher. Then what is the optimal algorithm for unloading the dishwasher? How do we even define optimal? We assume the algorithm can, at each step, make any number of calculations in $0$ time, by observing the configuration of the cutlery rack.

Perhaps this is an instance of a known problem? Also, there are many ways to generalise this e.g. number of cutlery types, number of pieces of cutlery, number of sides to the rack, a generalised cost function etc.

---

I have thought about this problem myself. I think the "sensible" definition of "optimal" is to minimise the expected cost of hanging the remaining cutlery. But it is not sufficient to simply minimise the expected cost of hanging the next piece of cutlery. For example, imagine one side is full, facing you, and the other side empty. But imagine $r$ only slightly bigger than $h$ and $t$ is considerably bigger. Then reaching around is clearly better for the next move. But it's also obvious that thinking in the long run, you're better off flipping if there's a lot to hang on the other side.